# I accidentally created a new Ext4 partition where my Windows partition was, can I recover it?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I was distro swapping and while installing Ubuntu I accidentally erased the partition with Windows on it, rather than the one with Arch on it. I erased it by deleting the partition and creating a new Ext4 partition with the installer partition tool, but I didn't write anything to it, or mount it.

[image: dev/sdb1 where my lost windows parition is]

I've tried testdisk, but it just finds the Linux partition data.

[image]

Is it possible to recover the Windows OS? Can I tell testdisk to ignore the linux partition data and read the actual raw files or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: Recovery by restoring data from your backups is generally easiest; any overwritten sectors will not have windows data on them,

Comment: Thanks. Not worried about data, just need to boot into windows for a bit.